# Cannot change .env value in octoberCMS

Tags: php, laravel-5, configuration, environment, octobercms

I have update my .env and all values of those configuration updated and changed successfully EXCEPT 2 of following attribute:

1. DB_CONNECTION
2. DB_DATABASE

As you can see, here is my db config file (.env):

```
...
DB_CONNECTION="pgsql"
DB_HOST="databaseurl"
DB_PORT=5433
DB_DATABASE=obunda_october
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=postgres
...
```

All of attribute values are changeable EXCEPT: DB_CONNECTION and DB_DATABASE, whatever value I put in DB_CONNECTION and DB_DATABASE it will always contain: **sqlite** and **storage/database.sqlite** seems DB_CONNECTION and DB_DATABASE hardcoded somewhere in code.

Could anybody help me to make it possible to setup value of DB_CONNECTION and DB_DATABASE directly from .env ?

note: I have tried config:clear, cache:clear, config:cache with no good result.

Comment: Do a full text search in your codebase for these parameters. Also it may happen that config read is successful but at consumption point you are using another variable.

Comment: Try to flush your cache? I mean Laravel stores the configurations in the cache. So you have to clean it.

Comment: I have tried all above ways but no luck yet, I have flush the cache, search the parameters in the whole code base...

Comment: can you share your `config/database.php` file, it may have those values

Comment: @HardikSatasiya here is the code https://pastebin.com/WBrZ4KBq , please notice dd(...) on the top of code, I debug the .env value from there

Comment: I think the only way to fix it is by replacing DB_* with new DBA_*

Comment: The OctoberCMS [Configuration Documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/configuration#environment-config) didn't help?

Comment: @kerbholz in my case it doesn't help

Comment: hmm strange issue